# how to return the value of a prime number while trying to print the sum of prime numbers in a range of numbers from check-prime to prime-sum

Tags: lisp

I was working on this question to print the sum of prime numbers in a range of numbers. The range values will be be taken as an input from the user. I got the syntax errors all cleared out but could not figure out how to return the value of the prime no. to the sum if it is true.

```
(defun check-prime(num)
(if (= num 1) nil)
;(setq i 2)
(loop for i from 2 to ( isqrt num) do 
(if (= (mod num i) 0) nil t)
(= i (+ i 1)) 
)

)



(defun prime-sum(*begin* *end*)
    
(defvar *s* 0)
(defvar *i* *end*)
(loop for *i* from *end* to *begin* do
;i= 13
(if (check-prime *i*) 
(= *s* (+ *s* *i* ) )
)
(= *i* (- *i* 1))
)
(write *s*)
)



(defun vals()
    
(print "enter the range1: ")
(defvar *begin* (read))
(print "enter the range2: ")
(defvar *end* (read))

(prime-sum *begin* *end*)
)

(print(vals))
;b =4
;e 13
```

Comment: That looks like common lisp... Why tag scheme?

Comment: Might want to make sure the code in your question is properly formatted and in code blocks so it's readable, too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your function, cleaned up a bit and formatted in a conventional way:

```
(defun check-prime(num)
  (if (= num 1) nil)
  (loop
   for i from 2 to (isqrt num)
   do
   (if (= (mod num i) 0) nil t)
   (= i (+ i 1))))
```

There are multiple things that are incorrect, and they boil down to how are Lisp forms evaluated.

There is a special form `progn` in Common Lisp that is used to evaluate a list of expressions, with the following pattern:

```
(progn E1 E2 ... EN)
```

A lot of other functions in Lisp are described has having "an implicit `progn`", that's the case for `defun` which allows for more than one expression in its body, but since the `progn` doesn't appear literally it is implicit. The behavior is however always the same: each expression `E1` to `EN` is evaluated in sequence, and evaluation of the whole `progn` are the values returned by the last expression, `EN` (that's where the N comes from in the name). In other words, the intermediate values from `E1` etc. are discarded, the expressions are only useful for their side-effects.

In your code, that's the case for `(if (= num 1) nil)`, which is an expression in the body of `defun` which is not the last one, and which doesn't even have side-effects. It is thus completely useless.

Likewise, in the `loop` macro, all that follows the `do` keyword are expressions that are evaluated for their side effects and do not contribute to the resulting value of the whole `loop` form.

In fact, `loop` is a bit complicated but here your don't have any *accumulating clause* in your `loop` (something like `collect`, `append`, `sum` etc. that would compute a result). Instead, your `loop` will always return `nil`.

Note also that `for i from 2 to (isqrt num)` takes care of incrementing `i`, you don't have to do it yourself like you tried in the `do`. Moreover, `=` is a comparison operator, in order to mutate `i` you would need to use `setf` instead: `(setf i (+ i 1))`, or `(incf i)` (which I repeat is unnecessary here).

To combine the first two expressions, I would write:

```
(if (= num 1) nil ...)
```

Where `...` is the `loop`: because if is a functional `if`, it evaluates to whichever branch is selected by the condition.

And inside the `loop`, I would use `never`:

```
(loop for i from 2 to (isqrt num) never (= 0 (mod num i)))
```

The `never` clause makes the `loop` compute a boolean and halt as soon as the result is false.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but the problem still remains in my head as to how to return the number from check-prime to prime-sum? 
Could you help me with how the returning of the number will work in these two functions ?